# How to send Xpath text through webhook?

Tags: python, selenium, discord, webhooks

So im trying to send this [value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lb4F.png) in this [website](https://www.coindesk.com/price/dogecoin) through a discord webhook with selenium (python). How do i do that? Heres my code that i have writen so far: from selenium import webdriver

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook
from selenium.webdriver.common import service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


#Import service=service
service=Service("./chromedriver")

#Chrome options :)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=./user-data")

#Running chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.coindesk.com/price/dogecoin')
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="export-chart-element"]/div/section/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div').click()
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="export-chart-element"]/div/section/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[3]').click()
price_send = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="export-chart-element"]/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div').click()
#driver.quit()

#Send it through discord webhook
webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='https://discord.com/api/webhooks/844456788626505738/s53WWXxYdBRtjLsAw95zT99vcYJf4-Z7dGopRcCInywi3TCrSs11KYvgCEGQ84xhello', content='Price: '.format(price_send))
response = webhook.execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all clicking on element located by `//*[@id="export-chart-element"]/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div` XPath does nothing since this is not a button.
If you are trying to get this element text you should do something like

```
price_send = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="export-chart-element"]/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div').text
```

And generally, you are using very wrong selectors.
For example instead of
`'//*[@id="export-chart-element"]/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div'`
XPath you should simply use the following class name `price-large` or css_selector `.price-large` so it will be simply

```
price_send = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.price-large').text
```

Comment: And how do i send it after?

Comment: This I do not really know, I'm sorry. I'm not familiar with webhooks. However I guess my answer will at least help you partially.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
price_send = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="export-chart-element"]/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div').click()
```

do this

```
price_send = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="export-chart-element"]/div/section/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div').text
```

that nunber is a webelement, you can click on it as well as extract the text. So in your use case you can get the text first and then send it to webhook or any other file as per your wish.

**Recommendation :**

It's always a better to use relative path than absolute path so try to write locators like this

```
//div[text()='Price']/../following-sibling::div/descendant::span
```

Comment: I already wrote this 7 minutes ago... And even more than just this